# LinkedIn API oath not authorized

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

What am I doing wrong? I am getting the following error:

Request token retrieval failed:

RESPONSE:

```
Array
(
    [linkedin] => Array
        (
            [oauth_problem] => Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : rw_groups, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : rw_nus, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_network, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_contactinfo, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_fullprofile
        )
)
```

And the input is:

```
[info] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
        [content_type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
        [http_code] => 403
        [header_size] => 825
        [request_size] => 527
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.449263
        [namelookup_time] => 0.06038
        [connect_time] => 0.079971
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.12454
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 243
        [speed_download] => 540
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 243
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.449258
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [primary_ip] => 2620:109:c007:102::5be1:f884
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => 2001:41d0:2:1db4::
        [local_port] => 55078
    )

[oauth] => Array
    (
        [header] => Authorization: OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="b1ad6a8df9577499135370c2d9c08650",oauth_timestamp="1432676525",oauth_consumer_key="75ge3aqksh0jlo",oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysocialreader.com%3A80%2Ffunctions%2Flinkedin%2Ffunctions.php%3FlType%3Dinitiate%26lResponse%3D1",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="3QURhE7qqlQgyak4apMgBfRiY00%3D"
        [string] => POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fuas%2Foauth%2FrequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mysocialreader.com%253A80%252Ffunctions%252Flinkedin%252Ffunctions.php%253FlType%253Dinitiate%2526lResponse%253D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3D75ge3aqksh0jlo%26oauth_nonce%3Db1ad6a8df9577499135370c2d9c08650%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1432676525%26oauth_version%3D1.0
    )

[error] => OAuth callback URL was not confirmed by the LinkedIn end-point
[success] =>
```

LINKEDIN OBJ:

```
LinkedIn Object
(
    [callback:protected] => http://www.mysocialreader.com:80/functions/linkedin/functions.php?lType=initiate&lResponse=1
    [token:protected] => 
    [application_key:protected] => 75ge3aqksh0jlo
    [application_secret:protected] => ws5bwvlaC5mu8IA2
    [response_format:protected] => xml
    [last_request_headers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Authorization: OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="b1ad6a8df9577499135370c2d9c08650",oauth_timestamp="1432676525",oauth_consumer_key="75ge3aqksh0jlo",oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysocialreader.com%3A80%2Ffunctions%2Flinkedin%2Ffunctions.php%3FlType%3Dinitiate%26lResponse%3D1",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="3QURhE7qqlQgyak4apMgBfRiY00%3D"
            [1] => Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [last_request_url] => https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
```

Comment: You shouldn't be posting your keys on a forum like this

Comment: Dont worry about the keys because you can refresh them. It is not a problem

Answer (score 2):

It's because LinkedIn changed their terms and conditions. For certain special rights you need to be approved by LinkedIn first as of May 12th 2015

[Request a review at LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)